# How can I price this magic crossbow?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, crafting

My plan is to have a Masterwork Darkwood Heavy Crossbow 430 gp, Quick Loading+1, Distance+1, Splitting Weapon+3, so that I can have a very long-range weapon. How much would that cost?

There's a table for this but for the life of me I can't make sense of it at all.

Comment: What is the base enhancement bonus of the crossbow?

Comment: base masterwork so +1 right?

Comment: @Mindwin Best to assume that's part of the question.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I've found a dupe candidate after your comment.

Comment: @Ozuma don't worry about the flag dupe on your question. there is no demerit in asking a duplicate, and we reallly don't care if you haven't researched before, like some forums do. We just like to keep these questions linked to avoid double work and to allow people to criscross the knowledge base with ease. Welcome and hope you stick around.

Comment: @Mindwin is absolutely on point. Also, feel free to pose separately any of the *other* questions that this question implies, like *What are the best magic weapon special abilities for a heavy crossbow?* and *What's the fastest that a heavy crossbow can be fired?* and *What's the longest range a creature can eke out from a heavy crossbow?* and *What prestige classes are best for a crossbow sniper?* These are the kinds questions the site loves to tackle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the price of the special material masterwork version of the weapon with the sum of all bonuses and a +1 for the base magic weapon (or the enhancement bonus you want).
Use the following formula: squared bonus x 2000 gp + masterwork weapon price + special material price.

- Masterwork Darkwood -> 430 gp
- +1 Magic weapon -> + 2000 gp
- +5 in abilities upgrading it to a +6 weapon -> +70000 gp

Total: 72430 gp.

Comment: 72430 gold.......imma be a very busy little warforged scout
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A weapon must first be masterwork before it can be made magical. Before magic weapon special abilities can be added to a weapon, a weapon must have a magical enhancement bonus of at least +1. (The +1 enhancement bonus on attack rolls for being masterwork is subsumed by the +1 magical enhancement bonus that affects both attack rolls and damage rolls.)

The final price of the weapon then can be determined using [this page](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/creatingMagicItems.htm) and [this page](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm).

That is, the weapon must have a +1 enhancement then it has *another* +5 in bonuses from the magic weapon special abilities. Get the price of a +6 weapon from the table (72,000 gp) and add the price of the masterwork weapon. For a heavy crossbow, that's another 350 gp. Then, if you want the crossbow made out of [darkwood](http://dndsrd.net/specialMaterials.html#darkwood), it's an extra 80 gp.

That makes the final price 72,430 gp.

Comment: @heyIcanChan thanks. being closed is no excuse to inaccuracy.